# MySQL ASCII codes 0-255

Tags: mysql

In Python, the ord() function returns an ASCII code between 0 and 255:

```
>>> ord("a")
97
>>> ord("b")
98
>>> ord("c")
99
>>> ord("á")
225
>>> ord("í")
237
>>> ord("Ñ")
209
```

But in MySQL, I'm unable to get those higher codes, even using charset modifiers:

```
mysql> SELECT ord("a"),ord("b"),ord("c");
+----------+----------+----------+
| ord("a") | ord("b") | ord("c") |
+----------+----------+----------+
|       97 |       98 |       99 |
+----------+----------+----------+

mysql> SELECT ord("á"),ord(_utf8"á"),ord(_utf8mb4"á"),ord(_latin1"á");
+-----------+----------------+-------------------+------------------+
| ord("á")  | ord(_utf8"á")  | ord(_utf8mb4"á")  | ord(_latin1"á")  |
+-----------+----------------+-------------------+------------------+
|     50081 |          50081 |             50081 |              195 |
+-----------+----------------+-------------------+------------------+

mysql> SELECT ascii("á"),ascii(_utf8"á"),ascii(_utf8mb4"á"),ascii(_latin1"á");
+-------------+------------------+---------------------+--------------------+
| ascii("á")  | ascii(_utf8"á")  | ascii(_utf8mb4"á")  | ascii(_latin1"á")  |
+-------------+------------------+---------------------+--------------------+
|         195 |              195 |                 195 |                195 |
+-------------+------------------+---------------------+--------------------+
```

How can I get those 225, 237 or 209 codes in MySQL? Which function? Which character set?

Comment: Accented `á` is ASCII code #160.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen in what charset?

Comment: @czuriaga python's `ord` returns not an ASCII code, but a unicode codepoint.